# 20.04 on XPS 13 9300 - opening lid skips lock screen

Tags: suspend, dell, lock-screen, xps

I have 20.04 running on a brand new XPS 13 Developer Edition. I've done very little customization so far, but I'm encountering a strange issue that makes me worried about the security of running Ubuntu on this laptop.

Several times now I've opened the laptop lid and it's booted directly to the desktop (no lockscreen) while throwing up a system crash dialog. "Lock Screen On Suspend" is **on**.

I think it's this one in /var/log/apport.log:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 12377) Thu Jun 25 14:28:59 2020: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
ERROR: apport (pid 16043) Thu Jun 25 14:38:17 2020: called for pid 12409, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 16043) Thu Jun 25 14:38:17 2020: executable: /usr/bin/gnome-shell (command line "/usr/bin/gnome-shell")
ERROR: apport (pid 16043) Thu Jun 25 14:38:17 2020: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)
```

And here's the output of journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell:

```
Jun 25 14:34:10 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: Enabling experimental feature 'x11-randr-fractional-scaling'
Jun 25 14:34:10 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
Jun 25 14:34:10 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: Will monitor session 2
Jun 25 14:34:10 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: Failed to create file /run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions: Error opening file “/run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions”: File>
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: loading user theme: /usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: Object Gio.DBusProxy (0x558553497910), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been>
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: == Stack trace for context 0x55855057b6f0 ==
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: #0   7ffe5c732de0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:256 (ca840092cb8 @ 26)
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: == Stack trace for context 0x55855057b6f0 ==
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: #0   55855095d650 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/fileManager1API.js:104 (39c750fd43d0 @ 28)
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: #1   55855095d5b8 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/fileManager1API.js:47 (39c750fd41f0 @ 108)
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: #2   7ffe5c732de0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:262 (ca840092cb8 @ 101)
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: g_async_initable_init_finish: assertion 'G_IS_ASYNC_INITABLE (initable)' failed
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: Object Gio.DBusProxy (0x558553497910), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been>
Jun 25 14:34:11 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: g_dbus_proxy_get_cached_property_names: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed
Jun 25 14:34:12 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: GNOME Shell started at Thu Jun 25 2020 14:34:11 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Jun 25 14:34:12 t-xps gnome-shell[12409]: Registering session with GDM
Jun 25 14:38:18 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: Enabling experimental feature 'x11-randr-fractional-scaling'
Jun 25 14:38:18 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
Jun 25 14:38:18 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: Will monitor session 2
Jun 25 14:38:18 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: loading user theme: /usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: JS ERROR: Error getting systemd inhibitor: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition >
                                              inhibit/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/loginManager.js:187:55
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: Object Gio.DBusProxy (0x5651f12f0900), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been>
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: == Stack trace for context 0x5651ee3cf6f0 ==
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: #0   7ffe35f77340 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:256 (43cf5a92cb8 @ 26)
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: == Stack trace for context 0x5651ee3cf6f0 ==
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: #0   5651f0ca28c0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/fileManager1API.js:104 (2e3fc89d53d0 @ 28)
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: #1   5651f0ca2828 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/fileManager1API.js:47 (2e3fc89d51f0 @ 108)
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: #2   7ffe35f77340 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:262 (43cf5a92cb8 @ 101)
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: g_async_initable_init_finish: assertion 'G_IS_ASYNC_INITABLE (initable)' failed
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: Object Gio.DBusProxy (0x5651f12f0900), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been>
Jun 25 14:38:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: g_dbus_proxy_get_cached_property_names: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed
Jun 25 14:38:20 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: GNOME Shell started at Thu Jun 25 2020 14:38:18 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Jun 25 14:38:20 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: Registering session with GDM
Jun 25 14:48:19 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Jun 25 14:48:20 t-xps gnome-shell[16080]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
```

Comment: Does it happen when you logout before closing the lid?